# Compare files script

Tags: bash

I am using this script to find information stored in one file using other file as a source for variables to look for:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
clear
file=/home/victor/Documentos/Temporal/13-06-04_Cuentas_para_revisar_cajas.txt
while IFS= read -r line
do
echo $line
cat Inventory.csv | grep "$line" >> cuentasxcajas.txt
done < $file
echo "done"
```

but the file `cuentasxcajas.txt` is empty, any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17291557/extract-strings-in-a-text-file-using-grep/17291633#17291633

Answer (score 3):

If I had your task to do, I would proceed thus:

```
grep -f '/home/victor/Documentos/Temporal/13-06-04_Cuentas_para_revisar_cajas.txt' -- Inventory.csv > cuentasxcajas.txt
```

No need for a Bash script, of for loops of for useless uses of cats. Just make sure you don't have empty lines in the file `/home/victor/Documentos/Temporal/13-06-04_Cuentas_para_revisar_cajas.txt`.